# scroll to active table row in a fixed height table

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with fixed height inside a div. I want to scroll to particular row in that table. I referred this link http://jsfiddle.net/SZKJh/1/, but it's not working for a fixed table height.
Below is the code snippet, please assist me to resolve this.

```js
function GotoRow(){
    var w = $('#forPmpIterate'); // my div 
    var row = $('#tableiterate').find('tr')
        .removeClass('active')
        .eq( +$('#line').val() )
        .addClass('active');
    
    if (row.length){
        $('#forPmpIterate').animate({scrollTop: row.offset().top - (w.height()/2)});
                               
    }

}
```

```html
<div id="forPmpIterate">

                    <div id="control" style="float:right;padding-right:15px">
                        Go to stage: <input type="text" size="5" id="line" />
                        <input type="button" onclick="GotoRow()" value="Go" />
                    </div>
                    <table id="tableiterate" class="table table-fixed">
<thead>
                            <tr>
</tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
 <!-- many rows here -->
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And my style is as below,

```css
<style>
    /* */

    .table-fixed thead {
        width: 100%; /*97%;*/
        padding-left: 4px;
    }

    .table-fixed tbody {
        height: 230px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
        display: block;
    }

        .table-fixed tbody td {
            float: left;
            border-bottom-width: 0;
            border: 1px solid #eee;
        }

        .table-fixed thead > tr > th {
            float: left;
            border-bottom-width: 0;
            background-color: #eee;
            padding-left: 4px;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your problem, here's the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/SZKJh/1084/

Here's the code

```
scrollTop: row.offset().top - singleTr.clientHeight
```

So basically you just need to subtract the top position value of the active row with the height of a tr. That's how you got the proper position to be scrolled.

Comment: Hi Balapa, thanks for the reply, good solution. But actually my table is having more than 300 records, for that reason i have fixed headers and fixed height for the table body. If you include these styles in your code, then its not working.  .table-fixed tbody {
        height: 230px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        width: 100%;
    } .table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th { display: block;}

Comment: **Actually, for display block its not working. In my page I have totally 3 tables, but for this particular table I need to scroll for particular row. Please assist me.**

Comment: Hi Balapa, I'm almost there..but as I mentioned earlier, i have 3 table in a page ( and each are in a div). But for only this table I want to perform this scroll operation. I changed oriDistance varibale to oriDistance = document.querySelector('#tableiterate >tbody').scrollTop; but it will go somewhere else and will be scrolling to top on next click. i checked modifying your fiddle example, like added more tables and i changed variable table as "var table = $('#tableiterate');" , with respect to id of table.

Comment: And if condition as  if (row.length) {$('#tableiterate > tbody').animate({ scrollTop: row.offset().top - singleTr + oriDistance
            }, 300);
        }

Comment: Actually I'm not that mch familiar with this jquery and all. I'm working on MVC, where I have multiple partial views, and this table is my 3rd partial view. I hope this document.querySelector('tbody').scrollTop; will work if we have only single table. Don't mind, I'm not able to achieve my req yet. But your examples are very helpful. Please assist me to resolve this.

Comment: Please provide your latest jsfiddle with 3 tables

Comment: there, 3rd table (rows are not loading, but that is the structurere). In my actual application page, var singleTr = $("#tableitera tbody > tr").height(); is returnig "zero" always. When I go to developer tool, there also tr height is "zero". Is there any alternative ways to get it without height of tr, please suggest.  use this https://jsfiddle.net/arcali2008/707q71w2/2/